# Incremental hot deployment on Tomcat with Maven and NetBeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, maven, hotdeploy

I'm using NetBeans 6.8, Tomcat 6, and Maven 2.2 and want to see changes in my code immediately in the browser (showing http://localhost:8080) after saving the file.

The tomcat-maven-plugin has the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
</plugin>
```

Following to the output it should perform in-place deployment.

What can I do to see changes in my Java code immediately in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It should do what you want. Painlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Hot Deployment of a Web Application with Maven in NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HotDeploymentWebApplicationWithMaven). I also suggest to check [Glassfish Hot Code Re-deployment (on Maven)](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic26320.html), especially the post about Compile on Save, and to try GlassFish, you may get better results.

Comment: I have the same behaviour on GlassFish. The only thing happened is that I cannot select "Tomcat" in the project settings after my GlassFish trial :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tomcat:inplace` goal to invoke your webapp from its compiled classes and sources.

You may experience file locking problems on Windows. There are several [workarounds](http://thedevelopercorner.blogspot.com/2007/01/tomcat-hot-deployment-in-windows.html), such as the `antiJarLocking` contet attribute, but essentially this boils down to your webapp not properly shutting down, whch will eventually exhaust your VMs memory after several reloads. In my case, I was using Spring, and the "proper" fix was to add a destroy-method on some key beans so that the app was gracefully shutdown.

[Maven Tomcat Plugin - tomcat:inplace](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/inplace-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to get this work.  Finally I just used jetty.  I put this:

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <reload>automatic</reload>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Maybe all parameters are not correct, but then I created a custom goal of 'jetty:run'
And I use that.  I can't use the big green play button 'Run', but the jetty deploy works nicely and it hot deploys any changes in the Java classes.