# Incremental build with NetBeans and Maven for jetty hot deployment

Tags: java, netbeans, jetty, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

After my [unsuccessful attempt to run Tomcat with hot deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756891) from NetBeans with Maven, I've tried jetty. The [jetty-maven-plugin doc](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) gave me an important hint:

> The plugin will automatically ensure
>   the classes are rebuilt and up-to-date
>   before deployment. If you change the
>   source of a class and your IDE
>   automatically compiles it in the
>   background, the plug-in will pick up
>   the changed class.

If I look at $myproject/target/classes/... in the projects directory, I can see that NetBeans doesn't compile and refresh the class file on saving. I need to build the project explicitly to update the file and than jetty picks up the change. (The plug-in param "scanIntervalSeconds" is set to 1.)

How can I tell NetBeans to compile on save and update the class file so that jetty can pick up the change?

**Provisional solution:** "Project Properties > Build > Compile > Compile On Save: For both application and test execution". NetBeans warns me that the result is not the same as with a usal compiler run but it works so far.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but what is not satisfying with the "deploy on save" option of the GlassFish plugin?

Comment: I've set "Project Properties > Build > Compile > Compile On Save: For both application and test execution" but cannot see changes in the browser after saving when using GlassFish.

Comment: @deamon. Your solution works for me (with scanIntervalSeconds set in my pom.xml). I recommend you answer your own question and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Project Properties > Build > Compile > Compile On Save: For both application and test execution". NetBeans warns me that the result is not the same as with a usal compiler run but it works so far.